# Plotting Single Band & Multi-Band Stacked TIFF File using Rasterio in Python

Tags: python, rasterio

I have 2 raster files (one single band and other multi-band stacked (465 bands) tiff file) which I am trying to plot using the following code:

```
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.plot import show

## Plotting Single-Band Image
with rio.open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\et.tif') as src_plot:
    show(src_plot)

## Plotting Multi-Band Stacked Image
with rio.open(r'D:\Weather data\et_stack.tif') as src_plot:
    show(src_plot.read([1,2,3]))
```

Using the above code both the images are getting displayed correctly. But the issue which I am facing is that when I am plotting the stacked image using bands 1, 2 & 3 (or any other band combinations), the image is getting displayed but with black background. This is not the case when I am plotting single band image i.e. single band image gets displayed with white background using the above code.

Can someone please help me out as to how I can display the image (stacked image) without black background.

Comment: Are you able to share links to the files?

Comment: Hi @snowman2....Due to proxy issues at our work place I will not be able to share the links to files....

Comment: Okay. A small sample of the file would be useful as well if you could create one. What is the nodata value of the dataset?

Comment: NoData values in my dataset is -9999.0 and dtype is float64....I would see if there is any possibility of sharing a small sample of data....

Comment: I wonder if passing `masked=True` into `read()` would help?

Comment: Nopes I tried that but nothing worked in that case....